# Rails In Cloud 9 - How To Access Gem Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

I have to edit gem source code but I can't access the directory in cloud 9.

I ran echo $GEM_HOME but I don't know where /usr/local/rvm/gems is in cloud 9.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the gem directory for the current version of ruby by running `rvm gemdir`. As to 'where' a directory is, you can navigate to it using the terminal, typing in `cd /usr/local/rvm/gems` will get to you the directory.